AWS Amplify Deployment Failing for Both Next.js and React.js Applications
I'm trying to deploy my Next.js application on AWS Amplify, but I keep running into an error during the build process. The error message indicates that a package.json file is not found, even though the file is present in my project directory. After struggling with the issue, I decided to try deploying a simpler React.js application, but I'm encountering the exact same error.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
For the Next.js Application:
I followed the usual deployment steps by connecting my GitHub repository to AWS Amplify.
My build configuration includes a preBuild step where I attempt to install dependencies using pnpm (since I'm using pnpm instead of npm).
The error I'm seeing is: ERR_PNPM_NO_PKG_MANIFEST No package.json found in /codebuild/output/src1064057875/src/my-app.
I checked that the package.json file is indeed in the correct directory, so I’m not sure why it’s not being found during the build process.
For the React.js Application:
I went through a similar process, but the error persists. Even though this is a simpler project, I’m encountering the same No package.json found error.

2024-08-10T11:20:48.923Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'React-Test'...
2024-08-10T11:20:48.924Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src1136899761/src/React-Test/.gitmodules
2024-08-10T11:20:48.929Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2024-08-10T11:20:48.969Z [WARNING]: ! Unable to write cache: {"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request failed with status code 404"})}
2024-08-10T11:20:48.969Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2024-08-10T11:20:48.969Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/dlz7sqplffptg/main/","WithDecryption":true}
2024-08-10T11:20:49.024Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2024-08-10T11:20:49.940Z [INFO]: No live updates for this build run
2024-08-10T11:20:49.944Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2024-08-10T11:20:49.994Z [INFO]: # Retrieved cache
2024-08-10T11:20:53.726Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                 ## Completed Backend Build
2024-08-10T11:20:53.731Z [INFO]: {"backendDuration": 0}
                                 ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2024-08-10T11:21:06.367Z [WARNING]: npm
2024-08-10T11:21:06.376Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ENOENT
                                    npm ERR! syscall open
                                    npm ERR! path /codebuild/output/src1136899761/src/React-Test/package.json
                                    npm ERR! errno -2
                                    npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src1136899761/src/React-Test/package.json'
                                    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
                                    npm ERR! enoent
                                    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-10T11_21_04_220Z-debug-0.log
2024-08-10T11:21:06.457Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-08-10T11:21:06.457Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 254
2024-08-10T11:21:06.458Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-08-10T11:21:06.458Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed


I just want to deploy my nextjs and reactjs application on aws amplify if not then can you provide any other reference to deploy my application on aws but not EC2

seems like you dont have package.json (or not able to read) on root directory.
